# How to custom enum with rails radio_buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to make a simple rating selection with star icon from enum in the form of a radio_button.

my model:

```
enum rating: %i(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

and my view:

```
= form_with model: @rating  do |f|
    .form-group
label.input-label.text-white = t(".title")
- Rating.ratings.keys.each do |rating|
  = f.radio_button(:rating, rating) do |star_icon|
    = star_icon.label { "i fa fa-star" + star_icon.radio_button  }
```

= f.submit t("submit")

Honestly it looks scary, so I want to apply a style to make it look like a real rating. The radio buttons on the left and right are just html icons

[image]

```
li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 10")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 9")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 8")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 7")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 6")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 5")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 4")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 3")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 2")
      li
        i.fa.fa-star title=("Rate 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I would take a completely different approach. There isn't really a good reason to use an enum column to save a rating value, it just needs to be an integer.

To capture the value in the view, a radio button is not the best look, I would use a little javascript (shown with jQuery here) and a little css to render a more typical rating selector (written here in haml syntax):

```rb
=form_for @rating, method: :post, remote: true do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :rating, id: :rating
  - (1..10).each do |i|
    .star{data: {rating: i}}

:css
  .star{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .star::before{
    content: '\2606'
  }
  .star.selected::before{
    content: '\2605';
  }

:javascript
  let selectRating = (event)=>{
    let target = $(event.target);
    let rating = parseInt(target.data('rating'));
    $('.star').each((i,el)=>{
      if(i<rating){
        $(el).addClass('selected');
      }else{
        $(el).removeClass('selected');
      }
    })
    $('#rating').attr('value',rating);
    $('form').submit();
  }
  $('body').on('click', '.star',selectRating)
```

it will look like this

[image: rating stars]

Now when you click on one of the stars, the clicked star and all stars left of it become 'solid' and all the stars right of it become 'empty'. Also the value of the hidden field is set to the selected rating, so you can submit the form and save the rating on the backend.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I send values? And why hidden_field?

Comment: And is it safe to do so? Are additional validations needed in this case?

Comment: @HarshBarash you send the rating value by submitting the form. The hidden field "captures" (by javascript) the value of the rating that you wish to submit. I didn't show the submit button for the form... my oversight

Comment: still can't figure out how to send values when you click on the asterisk? Without additional buttons. Ideas?

Comment: do you want to submit an ajax request, so that the page doesn't reload, or do you want to reload the page with a non-ajax request?

Comment: ajax would be perfect, but it would be cool to have any sender to start with. Thank you very much, in advance!

Comment: ok I edited so that it should submit an ajax post with the rating data included whenever a star is clicked. Look at the rails log and make sure that's what happened. I could've made a mistake!

Comment: actually it can be even simpler. You don't really need a form. If you have jQuery loaded you can just submit an ajax post request with the rating value as data. If I get time I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: to answer your question "is it safe?", well rails will only store an integer in the integer field, so no worry about someone trying to put js in there. If you're really concerned, you can truncating any submitted integer MAX_RATING (whatever that is in your app).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you, now I think I'm starting to understand js and haml.

Comment: then kindly designate this as the accepted answer, please

Comment: By the way, is it possible to somehow save the state of the stars when updating?

Comment: save the state in Rails, initialize a variable for the view like `@rating = Movie.find(id).rating` and then initialize the .selected class for the .star elements corresponding with the value of @rating.

Comment: yeah, I save it, but how to take it in JS?

Comment: you don't need to "take it in js". Render the view from Rails, with the .selected class applied as appropriate for the rating value